# When using coord_cartesian, y axis dissapear

Tags: ggplot2, coordinates, axis-labels, cartesian-coordinates

I have the following table:

```
x   var   y
a group1 0.5
b group1 -0.65
c group1 -1.3
d group1 0.2
a group2 1.2
b group2 -1.6
c group2 -0.7
d group2 -3
```

I want to plot x against y, in two different plots by var (group1 or 2), using ggplot.

However, I also want to "zoom in" into the y-axis, thus showing the whole x axis but, in the y-axis, only values from -0.5 to -3:

```
ggplot(table,
       aes(x = x,
           y = y)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(vars(var)) +
  scale_y_continuous() +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(-0.5, 
                          -3))
```

However, this removes the values and ticks from the y axis, and I do not know how to make them appear:

[image]

Comment: Try setting `ylim = c(-3, -0.5)`, this is a known issue in ggplot2 that should be fixed soon-ish. https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/3952

Comment: That worked! Thanks, if you phrase it as an answer I will accept it